# Span not changing value after clicking the increment button (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives, vuejs3

I am a newbie in Vue.js. When I click the increment button the span value doesn't change at all. I already add the method on click and add a condition to that. But it's still not changing the span. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="tr" v-for="(p,index) in cart" :key="index">
          <td>
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile is-hidden-desktop multilines">
              <div class="column is-half">
                <div class="buttons has-addons">
                  <button class="button test">-</button>
                  <span class="button test" id="value-quantity">{{p.quantity}}</span>
                  <button class="button test" id="increment-number" @click="increment">+</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- {{this.cart}} -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.quantity++;
      // this.price = this.quantityorder * 8000
      // alert(this.price)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cart: [
        {
          id: 4,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          quantity: 3
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          quantity: 3
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          quantity: 1
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          quantity: 2
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Can run here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hooks-3po0z?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change *quantity* of item in cart variable. now you are changing other data.

```
        <tr class="tr" v-for="(p) in cart" :key="p.id">
          <td>
            <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile is-hidden-desktop multilines">
              <div class="column is-half">
                <div class="buttons has-addons">
                  <button class="button test">-</button>
                  <span class="button test" id="value-quantity">{{p.quantity}}</span>
                  <button class="button test" id="increment-number" @click="increment(p.id)">+</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

and method:

```
    increment(id) {
      this.cart.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          this.cart[i].quantity += 1;
        }
      });
    }
```

you check here too: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-star-mq6o6

Answer (score 1):

In your `increment` method you're not referring to any specific quantity, what you'd need to do is pass the product ID to it, i.e. `@click="increment(p.id)"`, and then loop through your cart data properties and use an if statement to see if the ID's match, then increment that specific items quantity:

```
increment(id) {
    this.cart.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (i.id === id) this.cart[i].quantity += 1;
    })
}
```

If you want to add a decrement method you'd do almost the same:

`<button class="button test" @click="decrement(p.id)">-</button>`

```
decrement(id) {
    this.cart.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (i.id === id) this.cart[i].quantity -= 1;
    })
}
```

Comment: No problem @TechDev 